# Unknown domain owner?

Tags: domain

If a domain returns as picture shows who owns said domain and how would I be able to purchase it?

[image: PICTURE]

Comment: Nobody owns that domain. Contact your favorite registrar. I'm not sure why anybody would want a domain that is just randomly banging the keyboard though.

Comment: I"m guessing you're showing us an example instead of the real domain you were wanting to buy.

That message is your browser telling you only that it couldn't find an IP address for that hostname. It doesn't tell you no one owns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're showing us is an example instead of the real domain you were wanting to buy.

That message is your browser telling you only that it couldn't find an IP address for that hostname. It doesn't tell you no one owns it, just that your browser couldn't find an address for it.

You need to search in a whois database for the domain you want to know about to learn if it's registered.

Try mxtoolbox.com - they have a good set of tools for that.